# How to use Paper.js with angular 7+

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8, paperjs

I have tried to find a tutorial on how to use paper.js with angular but cant find a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

So through trial and error I finally figured out how to get paperjs to work.

First install paperjs via **npm**  `npm i paper`  or **yarn** `yarn add paper` or **pnpm** `pnpm i paper`

Second, in your html add a canvas element

```
<canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Third, in your component or page add

```
import { Project, Path } from 'paper';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  templateUrl: './canvas.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas.page.scss'],
})
export class CanvasPage implements OnInit, ViewDidEnter {
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvasElement: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  public canvas: HTMLCanvasElement

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = this.canvasElement.nativeElement;
    this.draw()
  }

  draw() {
    const project = new Project(this.canvas);  
    let myCircle = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 70), 50); myCircle.strokeColor = 'black'; 
    myCircle.selected = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: For Angular 11.2.14 I had to use **ngAfterViewInit** instead of **ngOnInit**. Otherwise _this.canvasElement_ was undefined at **ngOnInit** step.